# On units in subrings and quotient rings of a finite ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a finite ring with unity and $S$ be an ideal (or subring). Let $R^*$ be the group of units of $R$ and $S^*:=R^* \cap S$. Then does $|S^*|$ divide $|R^*|$ ? Moreover, if $I$ is an  ideal of a ring $R$ with unity, then how do to find $(R/I)^*$, i.e. the units of $R/I$ ? And if $S$ is a subring of $R$ containing the ideal $I$, then how to find $(S/I)\cap (R/I)^*$ ?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $S$ (an ideal) does not contain $1$, then $S^* = \emptyset$. But if $1\in S$, then $S = R$, so $S^* = R^*$.

Comment: @WilliamStagner : Yes , true , I see it now . But what about subrings ?